# How to create a new instance of the a entity without primary key?

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin

Apologies is this is a dumb question. I'm trying to get familiar with Kotlin and came across an issue. I have a kotlin app where I store data using Room.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
data class Link(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var _id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "link_url") var linkUrl: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp") var timestamp: Long?)
```

How can I create a new instance of `Link` without specifying the `_id`?

ie

`var link: Link = Link("url", 12334)`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try default value .. if you are using kotlin then it's useful ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create another constructor with `@Ignore` annotation, so that it will be ignored by Room:

```
@Ignore
constructor(var linkUrl: String?, timestamp: Long?) : this (null, linkUrl, timestamp)
```

If you pass `null` for the autogenerated field, it will generate new value automatically.

Comment: Why overriding the constructor while we have default value feature of kotlin??

Comment: @Moinkhan this is useful in situations when you need both constructors

Comment: that's what the default value in kotlin does. It will make 2 constructor ..

Answer (score 4):

Use default value in kotlin.

```
@Entity
data class Link(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var _id: Int = -1,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "link_url") var linkUrl: String?,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "timestamp") var timestamp: Long?)
```

Then you have to call like this.

```
var link: Link = Link(linkUrl = "url",timestamp = 12334)
```

Now here we need to use named arguments as our default parameter `_id` is first arguments. if `_id` would last parameter then you can call it directly.

```
var link: Link = Link("url", 12334)
```

**Note:** If you want both constructor in Java then you have to use `@JvmOverloads` on constructor.

```
@Entity
data class Link @JvmOverloads constructor(
   // .....
)
```

Comment: This would generate all the objects with same id & persisting would throw error while persisting.